# Use applescript to send imessage to new contact/thread

Tags: python, macos, applescript, imessage

I need to be able to send iMessages with apple script when that contact or "buddy" is not in the main iMessage Application yet. I am able to send them no problem if the thread is already created and has messages in it. But if i try to send it to one that is not the script will either fail or do nothing.

```
tell application "Messages"

    set myid to get id of first service

    set theBuddy to buddy "example@email.com" of service id myid

    send "Hi there" to theBuddy

end tell
```

Here is an example of the script I currently use to send a message, but as stated above this does NOT work if there isn't already a message thread, any idea how to do this? I'd rather not use UI callbacks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39548456/953553

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new conversation in iMessage using AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027839/how-to-start-new-conversation-in-imessage-using-applescript)